# I want to know the Confusion matrix Steps

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dataset, data-science, recommendation-engine

I've done the Count vectorizer with Cosine similarity. Next, I want the Confusion Matrix to get precision and accuracy

But I don't know how to do it
**I really appreciate your answers even though they are just steps**

**let me know if it is wrong / lacking in describe the problem**

code **Count Vectorizer**

```
    c_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    c_vectorized = c_vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset_with_tags.movie_tags)
    c_vectorized_m2m = pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(c_vectorized))
    c_vectorized_m2m.head(10)
```

[image]

```
    c_vectorized_m2m_similarity = c_vectorized_m2m.stack().reset_index()
    c_vectorized_m2m_similarity.columns = ['first_movie', 'second_movie', 'similarity_score']
    c_vectorized_m2m_similarity.head(10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the **confusion matrix**: it's used when you can **compare actual vs. predicted** values for a **classification problem**, thus giving you an absolute truth (TRUE/FALSE) as to whether or not **categories** were properly identified.  Eg how to [generate a confusion matrix from the resultswith a classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix
[image]

**Similarity matrices don't categorize**, they just provide you with **continuous values from 0 to 1** representing how 2 things are similar. **There is no classification, thus you cannot use a confusion matrix**.

Whether you want to use a **similarity matrix** (how similar are 2 items) or a **[classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html)** (eg whether a movie is a "comedy" or a "drama", movies can have several genres, eg "romantic comedy", so you will need a multi-class classifier), you **need some test data to assess the performance of your model**:

- **Similarity matrix**: list of movies which are similar/dissimilar and expect your matrix to return values close to 1/0 respectively
- **Classifier**: assuming the `movie_tags` from your dataset are accurate, you can use those to train your classifier, and predict tags for movies which are not in your dataset (you can always use a similarity matrix later on to recommend similar movies based on those predicted tags).